# Find rank with query in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I know that this question is asked also before but i tried all of them but no one works for me because my query is a little bit different because it has sum function in query that needs to get sum and in base of sum to get the rank of the user.

So my question is how to find the rank for single user my table is this:

[image: table image]

currently i am trying with this query but this gives me all users.

```
SELECT u.user_name as userName 
     , sum(taken_quiz_points) as totalPoints 
  FROM taken_quiz as q
     , users_app as u 
 WHERE q.taken_quiz_user_id = u.user_id  
 GROUP 
    BY taken_quiz_user_id 
 ORDER 
    BY totalPoints DESC
```

Comment: And what is not working with the given query? What would happen if you add some `WHERE` condition?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use INNER JOIN when you query data from multiple tables.
Also, I don't think it's possible to ORDER BY an alias, you have to repeat the operation of the alias.
If you want to have the rank of a single user you have to add a WHERE condition, like `WHERE u.name = "toto"` or something.

You should end up with this :

```
SELECT 
   u.user_name as userName ,
   sum(q.taken_quiz_points) as totalPoints 
FROM taken_quiz q 
INNER JOIN users_app u ON q.taken_quiz_user_id = u.user_id
WHERE u.name = "toto"  
GROUP BY q.taken_quiz_user_id 
ORDER BY sum(q.taken_quiz_points) DESC
```

Comment: I'd do `GROUP BY u.user_name`, and `ORDER BY totalPoints`.

Answer (score 0):

So you need the whole dataset in order to know the ranking of the person. It's a bit ugly, but you can nest to get the ranking, and then select from the ranked dataset the person you are interested in:-

```
Select userName, user_rank from 

(Select userName,totalpoints ,dense_rank() OVER (Order by totalpoints desc) as user_rank

from (
SELECT u.user_name as userName ,sum(taken_quiz_points) as totalPoints 
FROM taken_quiz as q, users_app as u 
WHERE q.taken_quiz_user_id=u.user_id  GROUP BY user_name, 
taken_quiz_user_id) aa
) bb
where userName ='bob'
```

Comment: i am trying this but this gives me error: # 1064 - Error in the SQL syntax. Please refer to the correct syntax in the manual at '(Order by totalpoints desc) as user_rank from (SELECT u.user_name as userName, s' at line 1

Comment: I think you were missing the user_name column from the group by statement. I have updated the script and it now works.

Comment: # 1064 - Error in the SQL syntax. Please look up the correct syntax in the manual at '(Order by totalpoints desc) as user_rank

from (
SELECT u.user_name as userNa 'in line 3

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running?